# Modify fstab file on servers

Tags: bash, text-processing, fstab

Platform: Linux 
Bash shell

Need to modify only 2nd column i.e mount points of NAS share /vol/wrm6 in /etc/fstab file.

```
NAS1:/vol/wrm6  /archive/net1  NFS default 0 0
NAS2:/vol/wrm6 /archive/06 NFS default 0 0
NAS3:/vol/wrm7 /archive/07 NFS default 0 0
 NAS4:/vol/wrm8 /archive/09 NFS default 0 0
```

The paths should be modified to have a suffix on the second column:

```
NAS1:/vol/wrm6  /archive/net1_05042018  NFS default 0 0
NAS2:/vol/wrm6 /archive/06_05042018 NFS default 0 0
 NAS3:/vol/wrm7 /archive/07 NFS default 0 0
 NAS4:/vol/wrm8 /archive/09 NFS default 0 0
```

whatever dir under `/archive/` for  NAS share /vol/wrm6 get appended `_05042018` like `/archive/*_05042018`. `*` means may be any dir

Comment: use [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed)

Comment: Need one line bash shell script to implement and check in one server first

Comment: bash isn't a text editor, it's just (your default) shell that then calls commands like ssh or sed or vi...

Comment: What does it mean to "implement on one server without open fstab file"? You want to edit /etc/fstab, correct?

Comment: One line shell scripts are so boring. Just a `#!`-line...

Comment: So, there's no requirement to check that the directory (the mount point) actually exists?

Comment: Why didn't /archive/07 and /archive/09 get updated in the output?

Answer (score 1):

This should take care of what you want and will add the `_05042018` to all directories that fall under `archive` when they involve wrm6.

```
sed -i -E "s/(.*wrm6[[:space:]]+\/archive\/)(.+)([[:space:]]+NFS.*)/\1\2_05042018\3/g" /etc/fstab
```

Comment: Thanks, But my requirement is whatever under /archive/ will get appended _05042018 like  /archive/*_05042018.  * Means may be any word

Comment: answer updated to cover any dir under archive as you have asked.

Comment: Jeff, there are many NAS mounts in fstab file, I want to update only for above NAS:/vol/wrm6  /archive/. I tried to grep "wrm6" /etc/fstab | sed ..that you suggested , but didn't work.

Comment: updated answer to only address wrm6.  Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

The following script would

1. check that the new mount points actually exists (and abort otherwise),
2. make a dated backup of the existing `/etc/fstab` file, and finally
3. modify the `/etc/fstab` file.

I would recommend to run it on a *copy* of the `fstab` file a few times to make sure that it works on your system.  Just change the `fstab` variable at the top of the script to point to a different file.

The script only *adds* a suffix to the mount point. It doesn't try to remove it if there is already one there.

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e  # terminate on errors (don't remove!)

fstab='/etc/fstab'                    # these could be made command line arguments
device_pattern='^NAS[0-9]:/vol/wrm6'  # but I kept them like this for simplicity
dir_pattern='^/archive/'
suffix='_05042018'

# Check for non-existing mount points
awk -v suf="$suffix" -v dev="$device_pattern" -v dir="$dir_pattern" \
    '$1 ~ dev && $2 ~ dir { print NR, $1, $2 suf }' "$fstab" |
while read lineno device mtpoint; do
    if [ ! -d "$mtpoint" ]; then
        printf 'Mount point "%s" for "%s" is missing on line %d of %s\n' \
            "$mtpoint" "$device" "$lineno" "$fstab" >&2
        #exit 1
    fi
done

# Make backup
bkname="$fstab-backup.$(date +%F_%H%M%S)"
cp "$fstab" "$bkname"

# Modify file
awk -v suf="$suffix" -v dev="$device_pattern" -v dir="$dir_pattern" \
    '$1 ~ dev && $2 ~ dir { $2 = $2 suf } 1' "$bkname" >"$fstab"

echo 'Done.'
echo 'New fstab:'
cat "$fstab"
```

---

The "don't remove!" comment is for real.  If `set -e` is removed, then the script would not terminate if an invalid mount point is found (at least when running under `bash` or `pdksh`).

Comment: Just a note that while this is comprehensive, the OP was looking for a one-line script.

Comment: Thanks Kusalananda, your script worked in the server. I have modified my question for other server which having little bit different requirement. Can we use same script with some modifications?

Comment: @Nirmal I've made the script more robust and able to use a pattern rather than a fixed string to pick the right first column in the file. Since this is not a script writing service and since I have no personal use for this script, I will make no further improvements to it unless it's something that interests me personally.